# Problem : UIScrollview bouncing makes Parent UIScrollview bouncing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, bounce

I have a fullscreen UIScrollview(B) in a fullscreen UIScrollview(A).

- A has a contentsize = number of page Horizontally
- B has a contentsize = number of Subpage Vertically
- Inside B , I have a small UIscrollview (C) that scroll in the same direction than B... So vertically too.

When C is wildly scrolling, it creates a hard bouncing effect when the end of the contentSize is arrived.

the problem : IT CREATES ALSO A BOUNCING EFFET ON B!!!! is there a way to suppress this contamination of the bounce effect between parents and childs without suppress the bounce effet of both.

Thanks

Comment: is your finger outside C (i.e. in B) when it starts to bounce?

Comment: the movement starts in C and yes the finger is outside C when it starts to bounce. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

The Apple documentation warns against similar designs.  From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html):

> **Important:** You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

I would extend this warning to nested UIScrollViews for the reasons you've discovered.

You can pull it off an analog of the nested A/B/C UIScrollViews by doing roughly what the mobile Safari browser does.  The user is either in "web page select" mode (your A&B views) or in "view web page" mode (Your C view).  A button in Safari's custom WebView controller allows the user to jump out of "view web page" mode to "web page select" mode, which is a UIScrollView with thumbnails of each of the pages currently active.

So, in your case, that would mean pulling C out of the nested UIScrollViews, adding a button to the C view controller that presents the A&B view controller, and maybe creating another controller class to glue it all together.

I'd also advocate combining A&B into a single UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apple iOS Scroll View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html) now..

> To create a rich user experience, you may want to nest scroll views in your application. Before iOS 3.0 it was difficult, if not impossible to accomplish this. In iOS 3.0, this functionality is fully supported and works automatically.

So nesting scrollviews is perfectly fine > iOS 3. To answer your question, I added scrollview C as a subview to a "container" UIView - before adding that container view to scrollview B. Seems to stop the bounce pulling the parent scroll view down, although I did have to swipe pretty hard and fast to make it exhibit the behaviour you described without the container view.

```
@interface TiledScrollView : UIScrollView @end

@implementation TiledScrollView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 10.f;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setContentSize:(CGSize)contentSize
{
    [super setContentSize:contentSize];

    BOOL horizontal = contentSize.width > self.frame.size.width;

    if(horizontal)
    {
        CGFloat col = self.contentSize.width / 10.f;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * col, 0, col, self.contentSize.height)];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:(arc4random() % 100) / 100.f saturation:1.f brightness:1.f alpha:1.f];
            [self addSubview:view];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CGFloat row = self.contentSize.height / 10.f;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, i * row, self.contentSize.width, row)];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:(arc4random() % 100) / 100.f saturation:1.f brightness:1.f alpha:1.f];
            [self addSubview:view];
        }
    }
}

@end

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect bounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    TiledScrollView * A = [[TiledScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height)];
    TiledScrollView * B = [[TiledScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height / 2.f)];
    TiledScrollView * C = [[TiledScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height / 4.f)];

    [A setContentSize:CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width * 4, bounds.size.height)];
    [B setContentSize:CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height * 4)];
    [C setContentSize:CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height * 4)];

    UIView * container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height / 4.f)];

    [container addSubview:C];
    [B addSubview:container];
    [A addSubview:B];
    [self.view addSubview:A];
}

@end
```